# PyQt5: Get list of all properties in an object (QPushButton)

Tags: python, qt, properties, pyqt, pyqt5

Using .setProperty I have assigned a few properties, dynamic properties if I'm not mistaken, to a QPushButton. I would like to be able to get a list of all the properties for that button, ideally I would just want the 'button' and 'test' properties that I have added. I tried 'QObject.dynamicPropertyNames' but it gives me an output that I do not understand nor am I sure if it is what I am looking for.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(400, 400))    
        texts= ['button1']
        self.pybutton = {}

        list_props = QPushButton('list_props', self)
        list_props.clicked.connect(self.list_props)
        list_props.resize(100,115)


        for x, (text, t) in enumerate(zip(texts, range(300,0,-100))):
            btn = QPushButton(text, self) 
            btn.setObjectName('btn{}'.format(x+1))
            btn.resize(100,100)
            btn.move(t,100)
            btn.setStyleSheet('QPushButton::menu-indicator { image: none; }')

            menu = QMenu()
            btn.setMenu(menu)
            args = ("button", btn)
            args2 = ("test", btn)
            menu.setProperty(*args)
            for act in ("item1", "item2", "item3"):
                action = menu.addAction('item1',self.status)
                action.setProperty(*args)
                action.setProperty(*args2)
            menu2 = menu.addMenu('menu2')
            action = menu2.addAction('item4', self.status)
            action.setProperty(*args)
            action.setProperty(*args2)
            self.pybutton[str(x+1)] = btn

        self.statusBar()

    def status(self):
        action = self.sender()
        btn = action.property("button")
        self.statusBar().showMessage('{} was pressed with button: {}'.format(action.text(), btn.text()))


    def list_props(self):
        for i in self.pybutton:
            x = self.pybutton[str(i)]
            print(x.objectName(),x.text())
            p = QObject.dynamicPropertyNames(x)
            print(p)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWin = MainWindow()
    mainWin.show()
    sys.exit( app.exec_() )
```

**Output:**

```
[PyQt5.QtCore.QByteArray(b'_q_styleSheetWidgetFont'), 
PyQt5.QtCore.QByteArray(b'_q_stylestate'), 
PyQt5.QtCore.QByteArray(b'_q_stylerect'), 
PyQt5.QtCore.QByteArray(b'_q_isdefault'), 
PyQt5.QtCore.QByteArray(b'_q_no_animation')]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check your code clearly you will see that you have not established any dynamic properties to the `QPushButton` except the `styleSheet`.

```
...
for x, (text, t) in enumerate(zip(texts, range(300,0,-100))):
    btn = QPushButton(text, self) 
    ...
    menu = QMenu()
    btn.setMenu(menu)
    args = ("button", btn)
    args2 = ("test", btn)
    menu.setProperty(*args) # You have created a dynamic property to QMenu.
    for act in ("item1", "item2", "item3"):
        action = menu.addAction('item1',self.status)
        action.setProperty(*args) # You have created a dynamic property to QAction
        action.setProperty(*args2) # You have created a dynamic property to QAction
    menu2 = menu.addMenu('menu2')
    action = menu2.addAction('item4', self.status)
    action.setProperty(*args) # You have created a dynamic property to QAction
    action.setProperty(*args2) # You have created a dynamic property to QAction
    self.pybutton[str(x+1)] = btn
...
```

I will improve your code and every time you print you will get the dynamic properties of the widget if you have it.

```
def list_props(self):
    for topLevel in QApplication.topLevelWidgets():
        for children in topLevel.findChildren(QObject):
            dproperties_names = children.dynamicPropertyNames()
            if dproperties_names:
                print("{}: ".format(children))
                for property_name in dproperties_names:
                    print("\t{}:{}".format(property_name, children.property(property_name)))
```

Output:

```
<PyQt5.QtWidgets.QAction object at 0x7f251731aca8>: 
    b'button':<PyQt5.QtWidgets.QPushButton object at 0x7f251731a948>
    b'test':<PyQt5.QtWidgets.QPushButton object at 0x7f251731a948>
<PyQt5.QtWidgets.QPushButton object at 0x7f251731a948>: 
    b'_q_styleSheetWidgetFont':<PyQt5.QtGui.QFont object at 0x7f25172975f8>
<PyQt5.QtWidgets.QAction object at 0x7f251731aa68>: 
    b'button':<PyQt5.QtWidgets.QPushButton object at 0x7f251731a948>
    b'test':<PyQt5.QtWidgets.QPushButton object at 0x7f251731a948>
<PyQt5.QtWidgets.QAction object at 0x7f251731aaf8>: 
    b'button':<PyQt5.QtWidgets.QPushButton object at 0x7f251731a948>
    b'test':<PyQt5.QtWidgets.QPushButton object at 0x7f251731a948>
<PyQt5.QtWidgets.QAction object at 0x7f251731ab88>: 
    b'button':<PyQt5.QtWidgets.QPushButton object at 0x7f251731a948>
    b'test':<PyQt5.QtWidgets.QPushButton object at 0x7f251731a948>
<PyQt5.QtWidgets.QAction object at 0x7f251731aca8>: 
    b'button':<PyQt5.QtWidgets.QPushButton object at 0x7f251731a948>
    b'test':<PyQt5.QtWidgets.QPushButton object at 0x7f251731a948>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def qt_object_properties(qt_object: object) -> dict:
    """
    Create a dictionary of property names and values from a QObject.

    :param qt_object: The QObject to retrieve properties from.
    :type qt_object: object
    :return: Dictionary with format
        {'name': property_name, 'value': property_value}
    :rtype: dict
    """
    properties: list = []

    # Returns a list of QByteArray.
    button_properties: list = qt_object.dynamicPropertyNames()

    for prop in button_properties:
        # Decode the QByteArray into a string.
        name: str = str(prop, 'utf-8')

        # Get the property value from the button.
        value: str = qt_object.property(name)

        properties.append({'name': name, 'value': value})

    return properties

btn: object = QPushButton('My Button', self)

# Add properties to the button widget. These can be generated in a loop if necessary.
btn.setProperty('property1', True)
btn.setProperty('property2', False)

print(qt_object_properties(btn))
```

Output:

```
>> [{'name': 'property1', 'value': True}, {'name': 'property2', 'value': False}]
```